# How to connect Jboss-as-7.1.1 with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jboss7.x

Does anybody know how to connect `jboss-as-7.1.1` to PostgreSQL?

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you read any of the existing documentation on the topic and, if so, what trouble did you have with it?

Comment: Also, how do you intend to connect? Using a JTA data source? Direct JDBC connection from the app via the DriverManager? What?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(Note that this was written for JBoss AS 7.1.1; keep that in mind if on a newer version, as things might have changed.)

[Download PgJDBC](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html). I'm assuming you're using `postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar`, the current version at time of writing. Adjust any filenames to match if you need a different version.

Now deploy the JDBC driver to JBoss AS 7 by putting it in the `deployments` folder or using the `deploy` command in `jboss-cli`. This will work for most, but not all, purposes.

Alternately, you an define a PostgreSQL JDBC driver module:

1. Create the path `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/postgresql/main`. The `modules/org` part should already exist, make directories for the rest.
2. In `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/postgresql/main/module.xml` with the following content, changing the `resource-root` entry for the PgJDBC driver to refer to the driver you wish to use.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.api"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
   ```
3. Into the same directory as `module.xml` place `postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar`
4. Start JBoss AS
5. Open `jboss-cli` by running `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli --connect`
6. Run the command:

   ```
   /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgresql-driver:add(driver-name=postgresql-driver, driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver, driver-module-name=org.postgresql)
   ```
7. Now create any required data sources, etc, using `postgresql-driver` as the driver name.

You can create a datasource via the web ui, with `jboss-cli` with the `data-source create` command (see `data-source --help`, `data-source add --help`), or by deploying a `-ds.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:/datasources/some-ds" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"  
        pool-name="some-ds-pool">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql:dbname</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>username</user-name>
      <password>password</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Comment: @abhishek No problem. You wouldn't normally get a complete answer to a question where you made no effort to explain what you'd tried, what you needed, etc; I only answered this because I happened to know off the top of my head and have written some documentation on it recently. For better answers in future, make sure to put more effort in to your questions. Remember, *you can edit your questions to improve them after you have posted them*.

Comment: i am new in this domain that's why so next time i improve my self and also thank you so much for helping me..

Comment: To get XADatasources you must install the driver as module.

Comment: @CraigRinger i'm trying to use the data-source create command for creting a data-source, i'm unable to do it.. i tried in many patterns but did not work. i want to have a datasource with `(name=PostgresqlDS,connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataBaseName,jndi-name=java:/Postgre
sDS,driver-name=postgresql-driver)`

Comment: @user2561626 please post a new detailed question and link back to this one so people know the context. If you like post a link to your new question here and I'll take a quick look, but I don't really work with AS anymore.

Comment: Beware: the file name is module.xml (not modules.xml)

Comment: Is this postgresql-driver thing now persistent_

Comment: @Zlatko Er... what? context? Link? What're you trying to say/ask?

Comment: The driver. Once I connect from cli wiht the **jboss-cli --connect**, does it persist jboss/server restarts?

Comment: @Zlatko Once you run the command in jboss-cli to register the driver then yes, it remains registered until you unregister it.

Comment: Isn't is required to start jboss-server before step 4? Otherwise I get "The controller is not available at localhost:9999".

Comment: @Marcel Yes, rather. Amended.