# Can't find suitable driver

Tags: postgresql, jboss, driver

I have a simple application that uses hibernate to work with db. When i check connection and some methods in main method, everything is fine. But when i deploy it on server, it throws

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Cant instantiate class: managed.ClientsBean.

javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

root cause:
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: managed.ClientsBean.
...


 root cause: 
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
...

 root cause: 
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

root cause 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project
```

But I have that driver, in `jboss\standalone\deployments` too. How can I make jboss see it?

Comment: What JBoss AS version?

Answer (score 1):

See here:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7

And here

[JDBC Postgresql driver on JBoss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873924/jdbc-postgresql-driver-on-jboss-7)